# Org babel javascript using incorrect path names

Tags: org-babel, microsoft-windows, cygwin

I am trying to run javascript code blocks in Org Babel.  My system is Cygwin on Windows 10 with Cygwin emacs-w32.  (Beautiful setup in general, I love it.  Makes Windows Unix-like and bearable to me.  But it does have its quirks.)  I have set CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native but I don't think that's an issue.

Code blocks in other languages work fine, but my node.js is a Windows program, so emacs-w32 Org Babel kindly translates paths from Cygwin to Windows.  The problem is I get this: C:\cygdrive\c\Users\me\all\the\rest\of\it, which has an incorrect and unnecessary \cygdrive\c at the front.  When I manually correct the path and type the command in at the bash command line, node produces the correct output.  What do I have to do to correct the path munging done by emacs-w32|org|babel?

BTW node seems to work just fine with relative unix-style paths that don't include .../c/... .  I would be happy to use relative paths for everything all the time ... would that be a viable strategy in general?

I have contemplated symlinking C:\cygdrive\c back to \ but that just seems like asking for trouble ... or maybe not?

Answer (score 0):

So ... I did it:

```
cd /cygdrive/c
mkdir cygdrive
cd cygdrive
ln -s ../ c
```

Now my javascript block executes as expected.

Who knows what else might go wrong? But tomorrow is another day, and another adventure with Cygwin.